# Openfire Content Filter plugin not working

Tags: openfire

i am using Version: Openfire 4.0.3 . and have installed Content filter plugin.

My issue is that, i am using Rest API to "SET" system property `plugin.contentFilter.patterns` . it works fine as i can see in Database table "ofProperty" the correct value .

But the updated words list doesn't update on plugin settings page i.e. https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:9091/plugins/contentfilter/contentfilter-props-edit-form.jsp

plugin setting page is showing default words. So , the newly added words doesn't get filtered.

any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the content filter need to be "restarted" afterwards? (to get the newest patterns)

Comment: @RomanS. how i can do that pragmatically?